# Displaying the output of a sorted array causes problem

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

I tried applying bubble sort algorithm to an array of values.

I have 5000 values in my input, from 1 to 5000. I imported values from a text file to create the array, which worked fine. The bubble sort algorithm also worked fine.

The issue is somewhere with the output. Some values do not appear in the output at all, whereas some values are being printed multiple times. I am attaching my code and the image of the output for reference.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    long int i, j, n, temp;

    printf("Enter array size:");
    scanf("%ld",&n);

    long int array[n];

    fp = fopen("5000averagecase.txt", "r");

    for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
        fscanf(fp,"%ld",&array[i]);

    for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
        for (j=0; j < n-1-i; ++j)
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }

    for (i=0;  i< n; ++i)
        printf("%ld\t", array[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbxVU.png

Comment: Are you sure your file doesn't contain duplicates as in your picture?! cause I couldn't see any wrong with your code!

Comment: You should check first whether `fopen("5000averagecase.txt","r");` fails by proofing `fp` for `NULL`.

Comment: Start with a smaller file (e.g. 100 values), and print the array before and after sorting.

Comment: The output loop is one part that looks good (apart from mystery that the output of 14 columns has only 1 value on the last line, not 2). Suspect the input data.

Comment: If your output is wrong, how could you say that the reading from file is successful ( it read what you expected ) ?

Comment: First check if `fscanf(fp,"%ld",&array[i]);` is successful.

Comment: How do you know that the output is problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file has only values from `1` to `5000` and I assume they're not sorted in any way, why don't you just make another file like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// shuffles an array given a pointer to the array and its length
void shuffleArray(int *array, int len) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int n1, n2, tmp;
  for(int i = 1;i < len - 1; i++) {
    // get random two positions in the array to swap
    n1 = rand() % len, n2 = rand() % len;
    // just swap'em
    tmp = array[n1];
    array[n1] = array[n2];
    array[n2] = tmp;
  }
}

int main() {
  FILE * fp = fopen("5000averagecase.txt", "w");
  // check for file pointer validity
  if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error: can't open the file!");
    exit(0);
  }
  // creating an array of 5000 number
  int arr[5000];
  // fill it from 1 to 5000
  for(int i = 0;i < 5000; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
  }
  // shuffle it
  shuffleArray(arr, 5000);
  // write the array in `5000averagecase.txt` for later use
  for(int i = 0;i < 5000; i++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", arr[i]);
  }
  // don't forget to close the file at the end
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Now after executing this you get your valid file, and after executing your sorting code on it you see that it works as expected